# Why is the eclipse Log Cat not working properly?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to eclipse, which I want to use to develop Android applications. I am using eclipse 4.4.0   with Android Development Tools 23.0.1.1256982. Once I run a project, I click on the upper left 'DDMS' button to see the Log-Cat entries, but I only see what is in the screenshot below:

[image: DDMS Lg Cat]

It looks like that Log Cat only shows the level of each log message, but neither content nor timestamp not anything else. How can I fix this in order to use LogCat to debug my code?

Comment: What is your target device?  Is it old or obscure?  It looks like it might be generating messages in a format which the DDMS parser doesn't understand.  You can always run adb logcat from a terminal/command window and process the output with generic commandline tools (more, grep, etc)

Comment: Yes, maybe I will dump eclipse for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have any devices that are connected to ADB. You probably need to get the appropriate drivers for your device or enable USB debugging. If no device shows up under the Devices tab (present in your screen shot), you will not see any log cat messages.

Answer (score 0):

Causes of Logcat stopping,

1. If you use multiple emulator same time it stopped work.
2. Change one emulator to another.
3. If you Don`t start a emulator.

It Solve by following steps,

**DDMS-> DEVICES-> SELECT YOUR CURRENT EMULATOR-> OK**

problem solved.

I think your problem is 3rd reason..goto AVD manager and start a emulator.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, it's not stopped, but rather failing to display anything after the letter indicating the log level of the message.

Comment: Please assume I know nothing about eclipse. I cannot put your suggestion into any context.

Comment: There are actually four layers here: the logcat program running on the device, the adb tool for running it and receiving its output, the DDMS tool for displaying it, and the Eclipse IDE hosting that window.  Only the first two are actually needed.

Comment: I still do not know how to follow the steps DDMS-> DEVICES-> SELECT YOUR CURRENT EMULATOR-> OK. Where do I start in eclipse? Drop-down menu, left side, right side, right-click somewhere, left-click somewhere ...?

Comment: are you start a emulator or not?

Comment: I am not absolutely sure, but I guess I did not start/use an emulator. I used a real hardware phone.

Comment: BTW, you can use standalone application for logcat. I'm using http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2454610
You can use it to test where the problem is.

Comment: ok. goto window -> android virtual device manager -> new -> create a new emulator -> start

Comment: If you want to run your phone,1.You need to install the driver from the manufacture to debug codes in your device.
Make sure in Settings->Application->Development, tick the "USB debugging" choice.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

I see the problem now. Eclipse J2EE is known to have conflicts with Eclipse ADT. You should maintain two different Eclipses for your projects, one for your J2EE projects and a separate one for Android. Or if you want to do some development on Phone Gap/Cordova, you should install the Web Tools Platform plugin on top of ADT.

---

Logcat seems to have worked in the past. One problem seems to be that you only have one column of logcat showing, the level column. Right-click on the header of logcat to add more columns, or click on the border of the column to expand it to the right, or the left.

The second problem is that the 4.x emulator is still really slow. That is why you're not currently being shown a device in the device panel window. You took your screenshot too quickly. To fix that issue, you should do one of three things: wait longer, test on an actual hardware device, or install an Intel-based emulator (just be careful of that last option, that option is complicated because there are several steps involved, and most programmers end up forgetting a step or two to make that option work correctly).